# Merge two sorted lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, merge

I am trying to merge two sorted lists in Haskell. The two lists must contain the same types, but the function needs to take lists with different types.

This is what I have got(I know that I need some code to avoid trying to take elements out of empty lists as well):

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] [] = []
merge (h:first) (c:second)  | h <= c = h:merge first (c:second)
                | h > c = c:merge (h:first) second

main = merge ['a','b','c'] ['d','e','f']
```

The thing is that I am new to Haskell and I get this error messege, that I kind of understand but don't know that to do about:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `[Char]'
In the expression: main
When checking the type of the function `main'
```

Does anyone know what this means? Help is really appreciated!

Comment: "but the function needs to take lists with different types" : I'm not sure what you mean here, but no, we don't need lists with different types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`main` needs to be an `IO` action. If you want to print the list, do something like this:

```
main = print $ merge ['a','b','c'] ['d','e','f']
```

Comment: Yep, that simple.  If you know C/Java/etc then think of how meaningful it would be to have `void main() { 62; }` - that's conceptually similar.

Comment: Alright! I thought that you only needed the main method to call your function, so I just wanted to get rid off the error message before I printed the result. So I didn't even think of that!

Comment: Sometimes I wish Haskell provided `mainVal` with a default `main = print mainVal`. But then I just fire up ghci and I don't really wish that any more.

Answer (score 4):

Note that your program does not run, because of "Non-exhaustive patterns in function merge" (that is, lists of length "1" are not considered). Moreover you can use "@" to make it more readable.

I'd rewrite it as:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] xs = xs
merge a@(h:first) b@(c:second)
        | h <= c = h:merge first b
        | h > c = c:merge a second

main = print $ merge ['a','b','d'] ['c','e','f']
```